# Creating buttons in runtime from Database field

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

I have a single columns table which holds 50 records. I would like to create 50 buttons from those records. How can I do that in Vb.Net?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this winforms, asp.net, wpf, silverlight etc? What information is in the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean Winforms:

Use your Datasource(f.e. a DataTable) and loop its RowCollection. For example:

```
Private Sub BtnLoadButtons_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnLoadButtons.Click
    Dim source As New DataTable("MyButtonTable")
    source.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("MyButtonColumn", GetType(String)))
    For i As Int32 = 1 To 50
        Dim newRow As DataRow = source.NewRow
        newRow("MyButtonColumn") = "Button_" & i
        source.Rows.Add(newRow)
    Next
    'you are loading the above DataTable from SQL-Server, now iterate the rows...'
    For Each row As DataRow In source.Rows
        Dim btn As New Button()
        btn.Name = DirectCast(row("MyButtonColumn"), String)
        btn.Text = btn.Name
        btn.Location = New Point(0, Me.Panel1.Controls.Count * btn.Height)
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf handleButton
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(btn)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub handleButton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    'do something ...'
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much Mr. Schmelter. Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in a Winforms application you can use the FlowLayoutPanel because it automatically orders the button layouts for you:

```
dim i as integer=1
for each record in Table
    dim btn as new Button
    btn.id = "btn" & i
    i+=1
    Panel1.Controls.add(btn)
next
```

Comment: +1 but you don't just need to use FlowLayout. You can use the i to place your buttons fairly simply where the Location x/y will be a function of i.